# How can I update a UIView's position and size in reference to it's superview's position and size? [Swift]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a superview  with another subview inside of it. The subview has constraints set to it to be centered in the superview and half the size of the superview.

The position and size of the superview are being changed when a button is clicked, but the position and size of the subview is not being changed with it. I tried using UIView.updateConstraints(), but it is not repositioning it or resizing it.

So my question is:

What would be the best way to resize and reposition the subview with respect to the superview?

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
func updateTimerFormat() {
        minutesContainer.frame.size.width *= 0.75
        minutesContainer.frame.size.height *= 0.75
        minutesContainer.center.x = view.center.x
        minutesContainer.center.y = view.center.y * 1.5 - 30

        // The minutes label is the subview of the minutesContainer
        minutesLabel.updateConstraints()
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?  You should be modifying the `constant` property of the relevant constraints

Comment: Should it animate nicely or just needs to be repositioned instantly?

Comment: I would like it to be repositioned instantly

Comment: Are you updating these in main thread? Also, try to call `minutesContainer.setNeedsLayout()`

Comment: I update this when a button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

You should not to call updateConstraints(), because I do not think your view's constraints need to be updated.

You just need to change SuperView's size or position. Then your view can automatically set the size and position, because you set their constraints before.

[image]
This is a demo.https://github.com/cythb/iOSIssues/tree/master/2_AjustSizeDemo

[image: constraints of subview]

Constraint subview(yellow) center to superview(green) center. Constraint size is half of the superview(green).

When you click button, you don't do anything else,just change the size of superview.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways-

1. Implement the `func layoutSubviews()`. This method is called when super view frame become change. In this method you can change your subviews frame.
2. Second option is that use autolayout during configure the subviews

Answer (score 0):

1/ Connect minutesContainer constraints to your ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var centerYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

2/ Change your updateTimerFormat method:

```
func updateTimerFormat() {
    widthConstraint.constant *= 0.75
    heightConstraint.constant *= 0.75
    centerYConstraint.constant = view.center.y * 0.5 - 30
  }
```